gcloud create artifacts repository is not working
I have tried running the command below
gcloud artifacts repositories create gke-cloud-sql-repo --project=unimitra --repository-format=docker --location=asia-south1-b --description="GKE Quickstart sample app"

I have checked the project name and location both are correct. yet I am getting the error below
ERROR: (gcloud.artifacts.repositories.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid project: "projects/unimitra/locations/asia-south1-b"


I tried running the same command
gcloud artifacts repositories create gke-cloud-sql-repo --project=project_ID --repository-format=docker --location=asia-south1-b --description="GKE Quickstart sample app"

and got the same error
ERROR: (gcloud.artifacts.repositories.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid project: "projects/project_ID/locations/asia-south1-b"

You are trying to create an Artifact registry under the  zone. Creating a Artifact Registry only supported under regions not zones.  Try removing the zone -b by ruining the below command and it should work as expected:
gcloud artifacts repositories create gke-cloud-sql-repo --project=project_ID --repository-format=docker --location=asia-south1 --description="GKE Quickstart sample app"

To view a list of supported repository locations, run the command:
gcloud artifacts locations list


Or, Check this document to view the Available regions
